# Numpy: how to return a list of most frequent numbers in each row/column

Tags: python, numpy

As the question suggests, is there an efficient way to find the most frequently appearing number in each row/column of a matrix?

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
r = numpy.zeros(shape = (2,3))
r[0][0] = 1
r[0][1] = 1 
'''
now the matrix looks like: 
   [[ 1.,  1.,  0.],
   [  0.,  0.,  0.]]
'''
numpy.argmax(numpy.bincount(r))
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
[1, 0] # 1 is the most frequent number in 1st row, and 0 for the 2nd row
```

When I call it i get the following error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you're saying you want each value in your result to be the mode of both the row and column it is in with respect to them original matrix?

Comment: @Alex in my example it was with respect to the row. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @turtlesoup Well that's what I want to know. Do you want it by row, by column or both?

Comment: @Alex by row. I did not know the implementation would be much different for either row or column